# ignore ajax setup

Tags: jquery, ajax

is there any way of ignoring the options set with $.ajaxSetup for a specific request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any built-in functionality to do this.  The *very* first thing any [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call does [is merge options with `$.ajaxSettings`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L202), there's no bypass for this.

Any of the [`$.ajax()` shorthand methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) ([`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), etc) are still calling [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) underneath, so they're in the same boat.

Answer (score 3):

This is kludgey but should work:

```
var origAjaxSettings = {};

function ajaxSettingsDisable() {
    jQuery.extend(origAjaxSettings, jQuery.ajaxSettings);
    jQuery.ajaxSettings = {};
}

function ajaxSettingsEnable() {
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.ajaxSettings, origAjaxSettings);
    origAjaxSettings = {};
}

//ajax request of any sort
ajaxSettingsDisable();
$.ajax({
    //Ajax request settings
});
ajaxSettingsEnable();
```

This could be extended to make it a jQuery plug-in.

Comment: jQuery ajax settings don't have all options by default, for example if you added a `success` handler it would still apply :)